# Dependence of A on B in an "if and only if statement.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

$A \Longleftrightarrow B$ means that $A$ is true only when $B$ is true, and $B$ is true only when $A$ is true. Does this mean that the truth value of $A$ solely depends on the truth value of $b$ and vice-versa?

Also, since $A \rightarrow B$ means $A$ is true if $B$ is true but it might not be the case that if $B$ is true then $A$ *has* to be true. So does this mean that the truth value $B$ is not the only condition the truth value of $A$ is dependent on?

Comment: Not exactly "depends on"... It means that the circumstance that one is TRUE and the other is FALSE is not possible.

Comment: "*Also since $A\to B$ means $A$ is true if $B$ is true*"  This is phrased incorrectly.  That means **if** $A$ is true *then* $B$ is true.  The structure of the sentence you wrote "$A$ is true **if** $B$ is true" is for $A\leftarrow B$.

Comment: Then can you tell me the correct meaning of $A\rightarrow B$?

Comment: It means that *if* $A$ is true *then* $B$ is true.  Here is an example... "*If* it is currently raining outside, *then* my grass is wet."  Here in our example when rain is currently falling the rain causes my grass to become wet.  It is possible however for my grass to be wet for a different reason such as me using my hose and sprinkler setup to water my lawn.  It is also possible for it to not be raining and my grass be dry.  In terms of math and logic, $A\to B$ is equivalent to saying (*and indeed is defined as saying*) $\neg A \vee B$

Comment: The important things here are to be able to recognize the difference between the statements $A\to B$, $A\leftarrow B$, $A\leftrightarrow B$, and so on... written in words as "If $A$ then $B$", "$A$ if $B$", and "$A$ if and only if $B$" respectively.  Yet another way of writing these are with the words "*necessary conditions*" and "*sufficient conditions*"

Comment: Does $A \leftarrow B$ mean the same thing as $B \rightarrow A$?

Comment: Yes, $A \leftarrow B$ means the same thing as $B \to A$.